# Numpy: Matrix Array Shift / Insert by Index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have an object where I have converted a massive for-loop method into a series of vectorized numpy arrays (about 50x faster).  Now I am trying to add a new method where I need to deal with a numpy matrix and then "shift" sub-array contents (i.e. insert values) based on the array index within the matrix.  I know I can accomplish this with a for-loop, but am trying to avoid that with the speed-up gains achieved by using vector math instead.

I was wondering if there is a fast and efficient way to accomplish the following:

```
import numpy as np

period = [1, 2, 3]

x = [1, 10, 100]
y = [.2, .4, .6]

z = np.outer(x,y)

print(z)
```

Results in:

```
[[  0.2   0.4   0.6]
 [  2.    4.    6. ]
 [ 20.   40.   60. ]]
```

I'd like to shift the rows in z to add the number of zeros based on period as the row index in z, basically the following:

```
[[   0.0   0.2   0.4    0.6 ]
 [   0.0   0.0   2.0    4.0    6.0 ]
 [   0.0   0.0   0.0   20.0   40.0   60.0 ]]
```

Ultimately, I'd be looking to sum on the vertical / column axis (axis=1).  I'd need a final array like the following:

```
[   0.0   0.2   2.4   24.6   46.0   60.0]
```

Comment: Be careful with time tests.  The non iterative answers create an array that is twice the size of the original. Iteratively you could sum the offset rows without that.

Comment: Is that `outer` an essential part of the problem, or just a convenient way of creating `z`?  Is this really some sort of inner product or weighted moving sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also calculate the indices first and assign at once:

```
a = np.array(
    [[0.2 ,  0.4 ,  0.6],
     [2.,    4.,    6. ],
     [20.,   40.,   60. ]])

s0, s1 = a.shape
rows = np.repeat(np.arange(s0), s1).reshape(a.shape)
cols = (np.add.outer(np.arange(0, s0), np.arange(s1)) + 1)
res = np.zeros((s0, s0 + s1))
res[rows, cols] = a
np.sum(res,axis=0)

>>> np.sum(res,axis=0)
array([  0. ,   0.2,   2.4,  24.6,  46. ,  60. ])
```

Comment: This worked great for me with one tweak.  The real "a" for me is not a square matrix, so I had to change: `rows = np.repeat(np.arange(s0), s0).reshape(a.shape)` to `rows = np.repeat(np.arange(s0), s1).reshape(a.shape)`.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the tweak. Updated my answer accordingly for the next help seeker.

Answer (score 2):

```
[[   0.0   0.2   0.4    0.6 ]
 [   0.0   0.0   2.0    4.0    6.0 ]
 [   0.0   0.0   0.0   20.0   40.0   60.0 ]]
```

is a ragged list.  We can build that with viectorized array magic, at least not with the ordinary stuff.

To get around this we need to either flatten or pad this structure

```
[[   0.0   0.2   0.4    0.6    0.0    0.0]
 [   0.0   0.0   2.0    4.0    6.0    0.0 ]
 [   0.0   0.0   0.0   20.0   40.0   60.0 ]]
```

or

```
[   0.0   0.2   0.4    0.6   0.0   0.0   2.0    4.0    6.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   20.0   40.0   60.0 ]
```

`sum.reduceat` lets us sum blocks of a flat array, but you want a skip-sum.  I suppose I could explore flattening the transpose.

My first thought was that the padded array looks like a diagonalized one, the [.2,2,20] layed out in on a diagonal, [.4,4,40] on the next offset, and so on.  I know `sparse` can build a matrix from a matrix and set of offsets, but I don't think there's such a function in `numpy`.  They all work with one offset at a time.

But it also looks like the kind of offset that `stride_tricks` can produce.

Let's explore that:

```
In [458]: as_strided =np.lib.index_tricks.as_strided

In [459]: Z=np.pad(z,[[0,0],[3,3]],mode='constant')
In [460]: Z
Out[460]: 
array([[  0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0.2,   0.4,   0.6,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ],
       [  0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   2. ,   4. ,   6. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ],
       [  0. ,   0. ,   0. ,  20. ,  40. ,  60. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ]])

In [461]: Z.strides
Out[461]: (72, 8)       # prod an offset with (72+8, 8)
In [462]: as_strided(Z,shape=(3,6),strides=(80,8))
Out[462]: 
array([[  0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0.2,   0.4,   0.6],
       [  0. ,   0. ,   2. ,   4. ,   6. ,   0. ],
       [  0. ,  20. ,  40. ,  60. ,   0. ,   0. ]])
```

That's the kind of shift we want, but the direction is wrong; so lets flip `Z`:

```
In [463]: Z1=Z[::-1,:].copy()
In [464]: as_strided(Z1,shape=(3,6),strides=(80,8))
Out[464]: 
array([[  0. ,   0. ,   0. ,  20. ,  40. ,  60. ],
       [  0. ,   0. ,   2. ,   4. ,   6. ,   0. ],
       [  0. ,   0.2,   0.4,   0.6,   0. ,   0. ]])
In [465]: as_strided(Z1,shape=(3,6),strides=(80,8)).sum(0)
Out[465]: array([  0. ,   0.2,   2.4,  24.6,  46. ,  60. ])
```

Generalization can be left to the reader.

Whether's any speed advantage is unknown.  Probably not for this small case, maybe yes for a very large one.

---

This cleans up the padding and striding a bit

```
In [497]: Z=np.pad(z,[[0,0],[1,4]],mode='constant')
In [498]: Z.strides
Out[498]: (64, 8)
In [499]: as_strided(Z,shape=(3,6),strides=(64-8,8))
Out[499]: 
array([[  0. ,   0.2,   0.4,   0.6,   0. ,   0. ],
       [  0. ,   0. ,   2. ,   4. ,   6. ,   0. ],
       [  0. ,   0. ,   0. ,  20. ,  40. ,  60. ]])
```

---

This ignores how `z` was constructed.  If the outer product is central to the problem, I might try the striding on the 1d `y`, and use `x` to perform a weighted sum.

```
In [553]: x=np.array([1,10,100]); y=np.array([.2,.4,.6])
In [554]: z=np.concatenate(([0,0],y[::-1],[0,0,0]))
In [555]: z
Out[555]: array([ 0. ,  0. ,  0.6,  0.4,  0.2,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ])
In [556]: Z=as_strided(z,shape=(3,6), strides=(8,8))
In [557]: Z
Out[557]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0.6,  0.4,  0.2,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0.6,  0.4,  0.2,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.6,  0.4,  0.2,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ]])
In [558]: np.dot(x,Z)
Out[558]: array([ 60. ,  46. ,  24.6,   2.4,   0.2,   0. ])
```

In this construction `Z` is a view on `z`, so is smaller than the `Z` in the previous.  But I sure `dot` makes a copy when it sends it to the compiled code.  `np.einsum('i,ij',x,Z)` might avoid that, doing its compiled iteration of the view without expanding it.  This may make a difference when dealing with very large arrays.

The result is reversed, but that's easily fixed.  I may even be able to fix it during construction.

Answer (score 1):

Looping over the first dimension works:

```
a = np.array(
    [[0.2 ,  0.4 ,  0.6],
     [2.,    4.,    6. ],
     [20.,   40.,   60. ]])

​
s0, s1 = a.shape
res = np.zeros((s0, s0 + s1))
for i in range(s1):
    res[i, i + 1: i + s0 + 1] = a[i] 

>>> np.sum(res,axis=0)
array([  0. ,   0.2,   2.4,  24.6,  46. ,  60. ])
```