# Get Max/Min from array based on another array using Numpy.where

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Starting with this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0,   2,  8,  9,  4,    1, 12,  4, 33, 11,    5,  3 ])
y = np.array(['', '', '', '', '', 'yo', '', '', '', '', 'yo', '' ])
i = np.array([0,   1,  2,  3,  4,    5,  6,  7,  8,  9,   10, 11 ])
print np.amax(x[:3] )         
print np.amin(x[:3] )
```

Trying to get the max or min value for the prior three items using `numpy.where`. So, in essence trying to use the "index" of array within the 
`np.where`. If there a more performant way to do this, please show.

Tried variations on this:

```
np.where(y == "yo", np.amax(x[:3] ) ,"")
```

result (why is it returning a string?):

```
array(['', '', '', '', '', '8', '', '', '', '', '8', ''], 
      dtype='|S21')
```

wanted:

```
 array(['', '', '', '', '', 9, '', '', '', '', 33, ''], 
      dtype='|S21')
```

Comment: You can't mix str and int in a numpy.array. See [dtype](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)

Comment: @Lucas, yes you can. dtype= "object". But thats not the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First look at the simpler version of `where`, which finds the indices:

```
In [266]: np.where(y=='yo')
Out[266]: (array([ 5, 10], dtype=int32),)
```

Evidently you want all the valyes for `y`, but replacing the `yo` with some value from `x`:

```
In [267]: np.where(y=='yo',x,y)
Out[267]: 
array(['', '', '', '', '', '1', '', '', '', '', '5', ''], 
      dtype='<U11')
```

`y` is string type, and since `''` can't be converted to a number, the numbers are converted to string.

Now if `y` was object dtype:

```
In [268]: y = np.array(['', '', '', '', '', 'yo', '', '', '', '', 'yo', '' ],object)
In [269]: np.where(y=='yo')
Out[269]: (array([ 5, 10], dtype=int32),)
In [270]: np.where(y=='yo',x,y)
Out[270]: array(['', '', '', '', '', 1, '', '', '', '', 5, ''], dtype=object)
```

the replacement is also object dtype and can have a mix of numbers and strings.

In this use all 3 terms have the same length.  In your use, `x` and `y` are replaced with scalars

```
In [271]: np.max(x[:3])
Out[271]: 8
In [272]: np.where(y=='yo',8, '')
Out[272]: 
array(['', '', '', '', '', '8', '', '', '', '', '8', ''], 
      dtype='<U11')
In [273]: np.where(y=='yo',8, y)
Out[273]: array(['', '', '', '', '', 8, '', '', '', '', 8, ''], dtype=object)
```

To insert `9` and `33` you have figure out some way of collecting the max of the previous 3 items, i.e. a running or rolling max.  `where` itself isn't going to help.

`accumulate` approximates this (this is the 'maximum' version of `cumsum`)

```
In [276]: xm=np.maximum.accumulate(x)
In [277]: xm
Out[277]: array([ 0,  2,  8,  9,  9,  9, 12, 12, 33, 33, 33, 33], dtype=int32)
In [278]: np.where(y=='yo',xm, y)
Out[278]: array(['', '', '', '', '', 9, '', '', '', '', 33, ''], dtype=object)
```

`xm` is not the maximum of the previous three values, but rather the maximum of all previous values.  In this case that's the same, but in general it won't.  For this `x` it is different for the last value

---

Here's one way of getting the max of the previous 3, admittedly a bit crude (with a list comprehension):

```
In [305]: x1=np.concatenate(([0,0],x))
In [306]: xm = [max(x1[i:i+3]) for i in range(0,len(x1))][:len(x)]
In [307]: xm
Out[307]: [0, 2, 8, 9, 9, 9, 12, 12, 33, 33, 33, 11]
In [308]: np.where(y=='yo',xm, y)
Out[308]: array(['', '', '', '', '', 9, '', '', '', '', 33, ''], dtype=object)
```

---

sliding window with `as_strided` (adapted from [Numpy: Matrix Array Shift / Insert by Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036229/numpy-matrix-array-shift-insert-by-index))

```
In [317]: xm=np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x1[::-1],shape=(3,12),strides=(-4,-4))
In [318]: xm
Out[318]: 
array([[ 3,  5, 11, 33,  4, 12,  1,  4,  9,  8,  2,  0],
       [ 5, 11, 33,  4, 12,  1,  4,  9,  8,  2,  0,  0],
       [11, 33,  4, 12,  1,  4,  9,  8,  2,  0,  0,  0]])
In [319]: xm.max(axis=0)
Out[319]: array([11, 33, 33, 33, 12, 12,  9,  9,  9,  8,  2,  0])
In [320]: xm = xm.max(axis=0)[::-1]
In [321]: xm
Out[321]: array([ 0,  2,  8,  9,  9,  9, 12, 12, 33, 33, 33, 11])
```

---

Using Paul Panzer's idea for just a few `yo`:

```
In [29]: idx=np.where(y=='yo')
In [30]: idx
Out[30]: (array([ 5, 10], dtype=int32),)

In [32]: xm = [max(x[i-3:i]) for i in idx[0]]
In [33]: xm
Out[33]: [9, 33]
In [34]: y[idx]=xm
In [35]: y
Out[35]: array(['', '', '', '', '', 9, '', '', '', '', 33, ''], dtype=object)
```

If it is possible that `yo` occurs in the first 3 elements, we need to refine `xm` with something like:

```
xm = [max(x[max(i-3,0):i+1]) if i>0 else x[i] for i in idx[0]]
```

otherwise we get errors from trying to take `max([])`.

Comment: what's wrong with MSeifert's "tweaked" `scipy.ndimage.maximum_filter`?

Comment: It imports `ndimage` :)  I could also adapt my `as_strided` answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036229/numpy-matrix-array-shift-insert-by-index/42036768#42036768

Comment: that didn't meet with much appreciation, did it? People want simple answers! Anyway, I've given it a mercy upvote ;-)

Comment: (Upvoting for clarifying some issues, ) if "yo" occurs randomly 1 or 2 times out 1500 samples.  and in some samples not at all.  Seems like solution presented is using alot of extra compute cycles.

Comment: @Merlin that's an excellent observation! you could use the one argument form of `where` to obtain an index array which would only contain a handful of numbers (one for each 'yo'), you could then use them to directly extract the triplets in `x` and `i` you want to max over. Conceptually simple and very efficient.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, can you workup an answer an post it. I am getting "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index" when I try.

Comment: Does my new implementation of Paul's idea work?  The only tricky part seems to be in handling `yo' near the start.

Answer (score 0):

The 'wanted' item I'm afraid you can't have because you can't have numbers in an array of string dtype. `where` in the form you are using it 'mixes' its last two arguments into one array. For this it has to pick a dtype. It is going for string because of

```
>>> np.can_cast(str, int)
False
>>> np.can_cast(int, str)
True
```

so str is the one of the two arguments' dtypes/types that can accomodate values from both arguments.

Data types aside you probably want to have a look at `scipy.ndimage.maximum_filter`:

```
>>> scipy.ndimage.maximum_filter(x, 3)
array([ 2,  8,  9,  9,  9, 12, 12, 33, 33, 33, 11,  5])
```

You may have to fix the offset to suit your reqirements.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you want but does this helps :

```
x = np.sort(x)
sel = np.where(y=="yo")[0]
y[sel] = x[-len(sel):]
```

?